# How to do a long division over a multivariate polynomial in Mathematica

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Does anyone know how to do a long division of a multivariate polynomial over another multivariate polynomial to effectively find the remainder, hopefully with fewest terms and/or lowest degree, in Mathematica? Many thanks.

Comment: `PolynomialQuotient` and `PolynomialRemainder`, the variable is specified as a 3rd argument. With this the multivariate case is probably covered.

Comment: @yarchik these do not work for 3rd argument is a list. It has to be one symbol there. `PolynomialQuotient[x^2 + y, x + y^2, {x, y}]` gives error `PolynomialQuotient::ivar`. I tried these first thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `PolynomialReduce` for multivariable polynomials.

```
p1 = x^3 - 2 x^2 - 4 + y^2;
p2 = x - 3 + y^2;
{q, r} = PolynomialReduce[p1, p2, {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

from help it says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice, although I cannot think of an example where for the 2nd argument consisting of only one polynomial `PolynomialReduce` would give a different answer from `PolynomialQuotientReminder`. That is even confirmed with a screenshot of the doc page.

Comment: @yarchik One can get different results in the multivariate case by specifying a term order that is not lexicographic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Indeed, you are riight, consider division of $p(x,y)=x^2+xy^2+y^4$ over $q(x,y)=x+y^2$. Depending what variable is selected, the result of $p/q$ is different: for $x$: $x^2+xy^2+y^4=x(x+y^2)+y^4$ and for $y$:  $x^2+xy^2+y^4=y^2(x+y^2)+x^2$.